# How to calculate: $\displaystyle \frac{1}{2}+\frac{3}{4}+\frac{5}{6}+.....+\frac{99}{100} $

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory

How can I calculate value of $\displaystyle  \frac{1}{2}+\frac{3}{4}+\frac{5}{6}+.....+\frac{97}{98}+\frac{99}{100}$.

My try:: We Can write it as $\displaystyle \sum_{r=1}^{100}\frac{2r-1}{2r} = 100-\frac{1}{2}.\sum_{r=1}^{100}\frac{1}{r}$

Now How can I proceed after that...

Comment: Looks good so far. Can you not use a calculator for the last quantity?

Comment: You got the summand right, but your bounds are wrong; plug in $r=1$ and $r=100$ to see.

Comment: Incidentally, does the question ask you to actually compute its exact rational value? A numerical approximation? What sort of lesson does this question appear in? (e.g. are you learning about estimating summations in a calculus class?)

Comment: The sum $\sum_1^{50} \frac{1}{k}$ is called $H_{50}$, the $50$-th *harmonic number*. There are expressions for good approximaions to $H_n$.

Comment: Notably $H_n\approx\ln n+\gamma+\frac1{2n}$, where $\gamma\approx0.577$ is the [Euler-Mascheroni constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant).

Comment: I suppose it's too late now, but this could have been a wonderful exercise in the use integrals to estimate sums; e.g. to compare $\sum_{n=a}^b \frac{1}{n}$ with $\int \frac{dx}{x}$ with suitable bounds on the integral to get an upper or lower bound on the sum as desired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sum may be expressed as, for arbitrary $N$ (where you have $N=100$):

$$\sum_{k=1}^{N/2} \frac{2 k-1}{2 k} = \frac{N}{2} - \frac{1}{2} \sum_{k=1}^{N/2} \frac{1}{k} = \frac{1}{2}(N - H_{N/2})$$

where $H_m$ is the $m$th harmonic number.

For sufficiently large $N$:

$$H_{N/2} \approx \log{\frac{N}{2}} + \gamma = \log{N} - (\log{2}-\gamma)$$

where $\gamma \approx 0.577216$ is the Euler constant.

For $N=100$, the error in this approximation is about $0.2\%$.

Answer (score 2):

In essence, you're asking how to compute $H_{100}$, in which
$$H_n = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}.$$
There's no closed form for these sums, so you may as well sum the expression for $H_{100}$ with a computer (or by hand, I suppose).  Depending on your application, the integral
$$H_n = \int_0^1 \frac{1-x^n}{1-x} dx$$
(due to Euler) may be of some assistance.  Or, you can use the estimate
$$H_n = \log n+\gamma + O(1/n),$$
in which $\gamma$ denotes the Euler-Mascheroni constant.  For reference, we have
$$H_{100} = \frac{14466636279520351160221518043104131447711}{278881500918849908658135235741249214
   2272},$$
and our asymptotic approximation gives
$$H_{100} \approx 5.18239,$$
which is within $0.005$ of the actual value.

(As it happens, $H_n = \log n + \gamma + 1/2n$ gives an even better approximation.  With this, we find $H_{100} \approx 5.18739$, which is within $10^{-5}$ of the exact value.)